# SQL Server Where date betwen start _date and End_date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have event table where I need to select records between days. my statements look like

```
Select 
    Event_ID
    ,Event_Type
    ,Event_Time
From 
    Event_Table
Where 
    CONVERT(char(8),Event_Table.Event_time,112) BETWEEN '20110501' AND '20110505'
```

The Event_time is DateTime format.

Now every thing look fine exsipt what I should do if I need the statement to request the date betwon as Date_start and Date_End any time it run. The idea is to request a new between date any time the scrpt run

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server?? 2008 introduced the `DATE` datatype which would be perfect for this scenario.

Comment: And if you're on SQL Server 2008 and you only need the date portion (no time information), you should use `DATE` instead of `DATETIME`

Comment: unfortunately it is SQL Server 2005

Comment: There's no "UI" aspect to transact SQL at all - if you need to *prompt* fro the start/end date, you need to use the facilities of whatever tool you're running from. You've indicated a preference to run this as a batch file, but I don't think there are many facilities available there either.

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @EndDate datetime 
set @EndDate = getdate()

declare @StartDate datetime
set @StartDate= dateadd(day, -5, @EndDate)

select Event_ID, Event_Type, Event_Time
from Event_Table
where 
    Event_Time >= @StartDate and
    Event_Time < @EndDate
```

if you need to include @EndDate then

```
select Event_ID, Event_Type, Event_Time
from Event_Table
where 
    Event_Time >= @StartDate and
    Event_Time < dateadd(day, 1, @EndDate)
```

Comment: my question is how to make the script to pop-up and request for date any time it execute. Date to be different any time it execute. The intention is to run the script by batch file.

Comment: @Faisal - you need to run query automatically, periodically? If it is automatic, for which period it should run, last week, last day?

Comment: @Faisal - I updated the answer with the example how to run the query for the last 5 days.

Comment: got this error "Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 46
Must declare the scalar variable "@Start_Date"."

Comment: @Faisal - on 2005, do `declare @EndDate datetime; declare @StartDate datetime; set @EndDate = getdate(); set @StartDate = dateadd(day,-5,@EndDate);`.